# getting error: invalid argument to unary operator

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Originally, I had all the code written below except `forecasttext <- 0`  but I kept receiving the error: object not found. So I defined forecastext to 0.

Now I'm gettin the error: Error in -html_text(forecasthtml) : invalid argument to unary operator

Any solutions?

```
install.packages("rvest")
library (rvest)

forecasttext <- 0

weatherlink <- read_html("http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?
lat=36.11479000000003&lon=-115.17280999999997#.WXfQRdPytE4")

forecasthtml <- html_node(weatherlink, "#detailed-forecast div:nth-
                          child(1) :nth-child(1)")

forecasttext < - html_text (forecasthtml)
```

Comment: The error message tells you where the error is.  You have a typo.

Answer (score 4):

```
forecasttext < - html_text (forecasthtml)
```

should be

```
forecasttext <- html_text (forecasthtml)
```

Comment: We all make simple mistakes when we're starting out, and even when we're not starting out :) If this answered your question, please tick the arrow next to my answer.